# Is there a video player on windows for iPhone recorded videos?

Tags: iphone, windows, video

I want a video player which can play iPhone 8 recorded videos on windows 10. Windows media player plays some but doesn’t play others ... same for VLC player.
Thank you

EDIT: 
More details were requested so here they are:

- Is the VLC media player updated ?List item 
  -> **Yes**
- The file format of the videos that don't and do playback? 
  -> .MOV doesn't play(except few which were actually live photos) /.MP4 plays.
- Do they play on a different machine? 
  -> No. Not on windows machine.
- are the files showing black, or what is happening when you
  double-click click them/open them in VLC? Any error message? 
  -> No error message on VLC. It doesn't play. Nothing happens on VLC whereas on Windows Media player it says an error occurred.

Hope that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume your videos that you can't play back are in the .HEVC (.HEIF for images) format, which are not natively supported in Windows. Therefore, VLC **should** be able to playback those files. Is it up to date?

To further address your issue, we need more info:

- file format of the videos that don't and do playback?
- Do they play on a different machine?
- are the files showing black, or what is happening when you double-click click them/open them in VLC? Any error message?

Comment: Wait a second I will give you more details...

Comment: VLC definitely should be able to playback those files. Since you say they don't work on windows, I assume they play back on macOS/iPhone. Trying a different video player might be an option but seems unlikely.

Comment: How did you get the files on your windows machine? Maybe they got corrupted when transferring. If you still have the original files from the iPhone, try retransferring them onto your machine. You could also try to encode the video with HandBrake (https://handbrake.fr) both on Windows and Mac (if available) and see what the results are.

Comment: I going to transfer again ...now

Comment: I installed ITunes on my pc. Synced it. Then I opened windows explorer and opened iPhone (which was connected to pc via USB cable) video folder. Played the video. Windows asked me which player to use. I said iTunes. It played exactly as expected.  Next. I opened Photos windows app. I tried to import all videos using USB as source option. It recognized 1044 pics and videos but it failed to import any. I have two questions : 1. How to see pictures and videos I synced with iTunes on pc(without using phone)?  2. How do I import iphones videos and pics to PC (the photos app failed)? Thanks.

Comment: Great work +1. This is totally on topic and your thinking totally is appropriate as a full blown answer.

Comment: Do you still have issues?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the Windows Media Player can play .HEIVC files after the installation of the HEVC plugin which is available through the Store.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/hevc-video-extensions-from-device-manufacturer/9n4wgh0z6vhq

Comment: Thanks that really helped. However still some files are not playing. I will update you once I have eliminated the chance of error due to file transfer.